# is it possible to link an exe file as a lib file to another project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, exe, lib

The question is in the title.

I have coded an .exe project, I would like to use one of the function of this project in another project.

Maybe it is a silly question, but if it is possible this would limit the number of projects in my solution...

I have given a simple try, I get an LNK1107 error.

I would say it is not possible, but it is hard to find a clear answer on the net.

Comment: No, this it not possible. Your question looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? Are you using Visual Studio? If yes, please add the corresponding tag

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes I am using Visual Studio. I would like to know the answer maybe on a "theorical" point of view. I am asking myself this question because I would like the exe to be also usable as a lib for the people who will use it...

Comment: @Richard I would like to avoid this way of doing it, *if possible*...

Comment: @SylvainB. However Richard's suggestion is how it is done usually.

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that I have only little experience in c++

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok then I guess I will do it that way....

Comment: @RichardCritten: Why are you answering in the comments section? We have peer review here.

Comment: The canonical way of dealing with scenarios like yours is to put the code you want to share among applications in a dll (dynamic link library).

Comment: It is possible for one .exe executable to spawn a process that executes another.    It is possible to create a library of common functions, and use that library from multiple executables.   But that those are different thing from using that other executable as if it is a library (e.g. being able to call arbitrary functions within the .exe executable).     Simply because executables are not structured to be able to do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because I think the question is too broad and my comment would need a blog sized post to be complete answer.   I was just hoping to point to OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

An executable is a standalone entity. It is the result of linking object files together to produce a self-contained, well, executable.

Linking two executables together will, at best, result in duplicate definitions of `main` (in reality it's a little more complicated, but…).

What you want to do is share the object files *before* they become an executable, and this is typically accomplished by moving your shared/common code into a "library" then link the library into both projects.

Alternatively, you could keep the executables all separate, but share the code at the version-control level, e.g. with SVN externals.